# Stop CSS3 animated objects from leaving div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

You can look at the page in question -URL Removed-.

You can see that a couple of the planets will float out of the wrapper div, is there any way I can stop it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the children elements are absolutely positioned, you need to relatively position the parent element in order for `overflow:hidden` to work.

```
#pagewrap {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    background-image: url("images/bg1.png");
}
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks :) I'll select it as best answer in a few minutes when it lets me.